# Class found in PhpStorm but not when running

Tags: php, phpstorm, wamp

I'm using PhpStorm to develop an iCal Manager.

I have a class `User` defined in the namespace `Engine` used for all the website, and a class `User` defined in the namespace `iCal` used for iCal process only, extended from `\Engine\User`.

When coding, PhpStorm can locate `\Engine\User` in order to define `\iCal\User`, but when executing I got a "Fatal Error: Class \Engine\User not found".

I'm using PhpStorm 2019.1 with PHP 7.2.4 on WampServer.

I tried to make an alias, didn't work. I tried to require all my files in one then to add it in 'Engine', didn't work either.

**\Engine\User:**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
//Created for IGPD by leroy the 27/07/2019

namespace Engine;
use PDO;
use Exception;
use PDOStatement;

/**
 * Class User
 * @property bool attendee
 * @package Engine
 */
class User
{
public function __construct(array $user)
    {
        $this->email = $user['email'];
        $this->name = $user['name'];
        $this->surname = $user['surname'];
        $this->language = $user['language'];
    }
}
```

**\iCal\User:**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
//Created for IGPD by leroy the 27/07/2019

namespace iCal;
use Engine\User as UserAlias;

/**
 * Class User
 * @package iCal
 */
class User extends UserAlias
{
public function __construct(array $user, string $cutype, string $role, bool $rsvp, string $partstat, string $sentby, string $dir, string $type)
    {
        $this->calAddress = "mailto:" . $user['email'];
        $this->cutype = in_array($cutype, ['INDIVIDUAL', 'GROUP', 'RESOURCE', 'ROOM', 'UNKNOWN']) ? $cutype : 'UNKNOWN';
        $this->role = in_array($role, ['CHAIR', 'REQ-PARTICIPANT', 'OPT-PARTICIPANT', 'NON-PARTICIPANT']) ? $role : 'OPT-PARTICIPANT';
        $this->rsvp = $rsvp ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
        $this->cn = $user['name'] . " " . $user['surname'];
        $this->language = in_array($user['language'], ['EN', 'FR']) ? $user['language'] : 'EN';
        $this->partstat = in_array($partstat, ['NEEDS-ACTION', 'ACCEPTED', 'DECLINED', 'TENTATIVE', 'DELEGATED']) ? $partstat : 'NEEDS-ACTION';
        $this->sentby = $sentby;
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->type = $type;
        UserAlias::__construct($user);
    }}
```

I just run the class file to check for errors, so I should not get anything.
The actual output is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Engine\User' not found in D:\wamp\www\IGPD\iCal\User.php on line 12

Here is `iCal.php`, the file that require all the files in the directory:

**\iCal\iCal.php:**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace iCal;
//Created for IGPD by leroy the 02/08/2019

require_once 'Alarm.php';
require_once 'Calendar.php';
require_once 'Event.php';
require_once 'FreeBusy.php';
require_once 'Journal.php';
require_once 'Todo.php';
require_once 'User.php';
```

Then I used this in my main page but it's not the one I want to load so I shouldn't need it:

**\Engine\Engine.php:**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace Engine;
session_start();

require_once "collections.php";
require_once "..\iCal\iCal.php";
```

I do not use autoload.

Comment: where's your require/include statement?

Comment: Are you using an autoloader?

Comment: To clarify previous comments... PhpStorm doesn't run the code at all, it just scans all files and collects classes as found. But your code needs a mechanism to include other files on runtime, as the PHP interpreter is fed with a single file and won't attempt to load any other file unless instructed to.

Comment: PhpStorm does not care where your files are located (as long as it's included in a project somewhere). But actual PHP when executing your code needs to locate those extra files: be it explicit include/require statement or autoloading functionality (your own or standard these days Composer).

Comment: I have updated my question according to your comments, but I have issues with the comment of @ÁlvaroGonzález, because so far adding a namespace automatically "searched" for the class or functions I needed while running my code (on Wamp or on my server).

Comment: I do not use autoload because I never heard of it (I'm a nOOb) but I'll look after it in the DoC

Comment: @CharlesLeroy then requrie the class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've explored the autoload solution mentioned by @ÁlvaroGonzález, and so far it's the only working solution. As a result, I came up with this code, in the `index.php` at the root of my directory.

**\index.php:**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace iCal;

spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
require_once    ucfirst($class) . '.php';
});

$e = new Calendar("e", "e", "e", "r", "e");
$f = new User(['email' => "", 'name'=>"", 'surname'=>"", 'language'=>""], "e", "e", true, "e", "e", "e", "e");
```

I'm glad to say it worked, but I'm afraid that is not the best solution, mainly because this code don't work if the class is defined in another directory.

Comment: It is a decent solution IMHO. The best part is that it's simple and it illustrates that you understand the internals.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `php foo.php` the PHP interpreter loads that single file and no other, unless you explicitly instruct it to do otherwise. On the other side, your IDE does not need to run your code. It just scans your project's directory, compiles all classes, functions, constants, etc. and assumes they're available when you ask about them.

Any complex program calls for splitting code in several files, thus you need to address it. Almost all solutions available involve [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) et al. in some way, but the details can differ vastly. It's also important to note that namespaces do not play any role in class or file loading—it's just a mechanism to have more short names available as codebases grow and third-party libraries thrive.

Your are using direct calls to [require_once](https://php.net/require_once) to load files. That's *roughly* equivalent to copying and pasting the included files's code in the exact location of the `require_once` construct, but there's a caveat: PHP parses each file independently and if you're loading a file with a class definition that depends on another class, you need to have that other classed parsed earlier. Look at this example:

```
<?php // Animal.php
class Animal
{
}
```

```
<?php // Cat.php
class Cat extends Animal
{
}
```

This script runs flawlessly:

```
<?php
require_once 'Animal.php';
require_once 'Cat.php';
```

This one triggers *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Animal' not found in C:\tmp\Cat.php:2*:

```
<?php
require_once 'Cat.php';
require_once 'Animal.php';
```

So this is your exact problem: you aren't loading your files in the correct order.

This can be tricky in relatively small projects and it doesn't scale well so that's why [class auto-loading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) was implemented. PHP provides a hook function you can customise and calls that function whenever it finds code that needs a yet unknown class. Your custom function gets the class name as argument and does whatever it sees fit (typically involving an `include` call).

Some guys wrote a spec on how an autoloader could work and called it [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). The well-known [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) package manager wrote an auto-loader implementing that spec. So, if you use Composer in your projects, you can benefit from that auto-loader without the need of writing any code. All you need to do is to follow a specific naming convention and directory structure and define where your classes root directory is. So, if you want a class called `\Engine\User` you define it in a file located at `/Blah/Blah/Engine/User.php` and the class is loaded automatically when it's used in your code.